# Keyboard and mouse no working in startup windows

Tags: boot

My computer power button is blinking amber.Monitor is black.
I replaced a new power supply and it's work.

However, I found the keyboard and mouse is no working after Windows start.
The keyboard and mouse can be use in bios.

I have tried the following way:

1. replace CMOS battery
2. unplug RAM and plug it again.
3. unplug power cable for a few minute
4. make sure USB CONTROLLER is enabled in bios
5. go safe mode (keyboard and mouse not working in safe mode)

but with no luck.

What is the other solution to fix keyboard and mouse not working in startup windows?

[image]

Comment: Have you run the BIOS/UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics for the keyboard, mouse, USB ports/motherboard _(these may be separate or just be the latter)_, and PSU _(regular and extended tests for each)_? Will the USB ports the mouse and keyboard are plugged into recognize a USB drive _(rules out the USB port)_? Does the keyboard and mouse work on another machine _(rules out the hardware)_?

Comment: @JW0914 keyboard and mouse work on another machine. How to run BIOS/UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics?

Comment: Entering hardware diagnostics varies by motherboard, but it's usually found on the BIOS/UEFI boot screen _(not the boot settings page in the firmware, but the `F12` or similar boot options screen)_, else it would be an option somewhere within the BIOS/UEFI settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to plug-off the devices and uninstall keyboard and mouse driver in Windows, then try to reboot and plug in both the devices. Windows should recognize them and it'll try reinstall drivers.

Comment: You can't uninstall the basic drivers Windows comes with that auto recognize keyboards and mice, however they can be if they're third-party drivers

Comment: How to uninstall driver? @Bellisario

Comment: @e12345678 you can unistall drivers following this [guide](https://www.pcworld.com/article/246041/how-to-uninstall-drivers-in-windows.html)...